# When I generate views from HAML files, where do the IDs come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

So, I have a Rails project with HAML views. When the view reads something from a model and that model throws an error, I get IDs in the stack trace for the generated view, like so:

```
Module::Class#method_with_an_error
app/models/model.rb, line 14
#<Class:0x00007ff44715ad90>#_app_views_my_page_html_haml__1235391671395365279_70343570677320
app/views/my_page.html.haml, line 35
block in ActionView::Template#render
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 157
...
```

This might be a silly question - but where does the 1235391671395365279_70343570677320 comes from? Is there a way to get rid of it, so it won't appear in stack traces?

Comment: Hello could you add the function `my_page` that come from your controller ?

Comment: it's anything that throws an error. The error itself is not the issue, just the mysterious GUID in the stack trace. :-)